# Disabling TextChanged function wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, function

Is there any way to disable a TextChanged method? I have to fill 2 textboxes (named A,B) with 2 calculated values in a TextChanged mehod but when i type a number into A, it calculates a value and fill B with it, but then the B textchanged method will execute then A.... at the end i get StackOverflowException
There is the code:

```
private void AB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == A)
        {
            B.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(A.Text)*27).ToString("0.00");
        }
        else if (sender == B)
        {
            A.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(B.Text) /13).ToString("0.00");
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: i want to disable only one of the method calling

Comment: I would do this with binding and backing variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable that determines if you are currently setting a value. Only if you are not, set it.

```
private bool settingValue = false;

private void AB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!settingValue){
        settingValue = true;
        if (sender == A)
        {
            B.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(A.Text)*27).ToString("0.00");
        }
        else if (sender == B)
        {
            A.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(B.Text) /13).ToString("0.00");
        }
        settingValue = false;
    }
}
```

When the method is first invoked, `settingValue` is `false`. It then immediately sets the value to true.
When setting the `Text`, the event handler is executed again. But this time it does nothing, because `settingValue` is `true`.
Then the first execution ends, setting `settingValue` back to `false`.

Comment: i tried this solution but it not work for some reason thats why i wanted to disable a method calling

Comment: Did you test this?  You set settingValue to true then false.  What is the value of settingValue going to be on every call?

Comment: @Frisbee The `TextChanged` event is called after the `Text` property is set. So for the second invoke of the method the value is true.

Comment: Either mark the variable as `volatile` or unregister the events with `-=` and reregister them with `+=` after the handler finished when the call comes from the wrong thread maybe?

Comment: @Adwaenyth This is an eventhandler invoked by a GUI element. It can only come from the UI thread.

Comment: sorry now i see what i did wrong, this code works thanks!

Comment: @Domysee then you're right of course and it must be a faulty implementation.